# Flutter, refresh screen after await call

Tags: flutter

Currently the only way I have to refresh the screen is using `Navigator.push()`.

```
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => this.build(context)));
            }
```

But this only adds another screen to the stack of screens.

How can I refresh the screen after calling my `print()` without having to use `Navigator.push()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set your class as Stateful Widget and use:

```
setState(() {
  // Add, edit or delete widgets
  // Set a diferent value for some variable
  // etc...
});
```

Or you can still use the `Navigator` but with the `pushReplacement` function, for example:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => super.widget));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setState` after request api response data,

`setState` is a way to dynamically change the UI.

It rebuild all current screen.

We call it inside the State Object class of the `StatefulWidget`.